# My prefix is the word I want

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, affix-riddle

> My prefix is the word I want, while it's an abbreviation.
> My infix is a negative that sounds like it has passion.
> My suffixes are two separate words which can describe the look;
> But users will not read through them unless they did what it took.

**What am I?**

Answer (score 2):

I think you are a:

> **[CHECKBOOK](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/checkbook)** (UK: chequebook)

*My prefix is the word I want, while it's an abbreviation.*

> What you really want to be able to give out right now is a **CHECK(MARK)** for a correct answer (i.e. 'check' here is short for - an abbreviation of - 'checkmark').

*My infix is a negative that sounds like it has passion.*

> A cry of **BOO!** is a *passionate* display of displeasure (e.g. in the theatre or at a sports match).
>
>  <sup>Alternatively, as suggested by @Evargalo in comments, the passionately negative expression '**HECK!**' would satisfy this too...</sup>

*My suffixes are two separate words which can describe the look;*
*But users will not read through them unless they did what it took.*

> The two suffixes referred to here are **BOOK** and **OK**, which can describe the appearance of a checkbook in good condition (the BOOK is OK). But how do you know? Well, first you have to CHECK it, which comprises the letters you *took* away here in order to find your suffixes :)

Comment: For the infix, it could also be rot13(urpx) with exactly the same justification.

Comment: @Evargalo I like that too - will add, thanks :)